# how to get nearest places around my present location?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using google maps sdk for ios to diplay present location in my iPhone application.how to get nearest places around my present location(just like whats app show location nearest places).

Comment: Use google place api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps SDK does not provide you with the places Data. Instead you will have to use the google places API. Check this out : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.so i need to use Nearby Search Requests ?